# Cant retrieve user by ID in Laravel 5.5

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I assume it's something right under my nose.

I am trying to retrieve multiple rows from a database by their ID, by subtracting a number from the original query like so:

```
$week4 = DB::table('weekly_territory_data')->where([['area_id', '=', $area_id], ['start_date', '=', $startDate]])->first();

Log::info(print_r($week4, true));

$selectedWeekId = $week4->id;
$selectedWeekIdSub2 = $selectedWeekId - 236;
$selectedWeekIdSub3 = $selectedWeekId - 472;
$selectedWeekIdSub4 = $selectedWeekId - 708;

Log::info($selectedWeekIdSub4);

$week1 = DB::table('weekly_territory_data')->where('id', '=', $selectedWeekIdSub4)->first();

Log::info(print_r($week1,true));
```

I know I am getting the right ID numbers, but I can't retrieve the rows using the code I have. What is going on here? Is there some sort of exact case issue?

Comment: `I can't retrieve the rows` - what does this mean?  Be specific - do you mean the query is working correctly, but you are getting an empty result set for `$week1`?  What do the results of your `Log`ging show?  Where is the user ID mentioned in your title?  The simplest explanation is there are no records matching your queries.  Are you 100% sure that is not the case? You have not ruled it out here, nor shown us anything to indicate that is not the case.

Comment: It is returning an object. How can I access the ID in the object?

Comment: @User14289 `$week1->id` is the secret to success.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent),
Assuming you created a model `WeeklyTerritoryData`
your query should look like this :

`$week1 = WeeklyTerritoryData::find($selectedWeekIdSub4)->first();`

or

`$week1 = WeeklyTerritoryData::where('id',$selectedWeekIdSub4)->first();`

this will return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections), then you can access id or any other field like this :

`$week1->id`

Comment: It seems liek in my database there is an issue with the ID field... 

When i look in the log on the server it reads: [ï»¿id] => 3131 ... there must be some illegal character

Comment: are you using a language other than English?

Comment: I must have imported the database incorrectly, i am using english... there must be some sort of character in the csv or something with the data import wizard in mysql workbench. ugh

Answer (score 0):

The issue was typecasting.

I was trying to get the data set with an ID, treating it as an integer... but my ID column is a string for some stupid reason.

```
    $selectedWeekId = $week4->id;

    $week3id = $selectedWeekId - 236;
    $week3string = (string) $week3id;
    $week3 = WeeklyTerritoryData::where('id', '=', $week3string)->get();

    Log::info('week3 to follow');
    Log::info($week3);
    $week2id = $selectedWeekId - 472;
    $week2string = (string) $week2id;
    $week2 = WeeklyTerritoryData::where('id', '=', $week2string)->get();

    Log::info('week2 to follow');
    Log::info($week2);

    $week1id = $selectedWeekId - 708;
    $week1string = (string) $week1id;
    $week1 = WeeklyTerritoryData::where('id', '=', $week1string)->get();
```